# Error including Boost Threading Library

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, compiler-errors

I have a rather large codebase that includes libSVM and lp_solve libraries. I recently added the Boost Threading library to the code and I continue to get a compilation error that I can't seem to solve.

First, I added the include statement for the threading library:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

Second, I adjusted the makefile for compilation. The command used to compile the relevant file is:

```
g++ -I./ -I../Eigen -I../Classification -I../Components -I../include 
-I../Individuals -I../Pruning -I../Pruning/AIS -I../Pruning/ACO 
-I../Pruning/GA -I../Pruning/PSO -I../Pruning/CFO -I../Random 
-I../Samplers -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fopenmp -llpsolve55 
-lsvm -lboost_thread -lboost_system  -MMD -MP 
-MF"Samplers/OMPP_Sampler.d" -MT"Samplers/OMPP_Sampler.d" -o 
"Samplers/OMPP_Sampler.o" "../Samplers/OMPP_Sampler.cpp"
```

The generated error is:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread.hpp:24,
             from ../Samplers/OMPP_Sampler.cpp:15:
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/future.hpp: In constructor 
‘boost::packaged_task<R>::packaged_task(R (*)())’:
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:3214: error: expected 
unqualified-id before numeric constant
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:3214: error: expected ‘)’ 
before numeric constant
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:3215: error: type/value 
mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class 
F, class R> struct boost::detail::task_shared_state’
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:3215: error:   expected a 
type, got ‘0’
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:3215: error: invalid type 
in declaration before ‘;’ token
```

I have dug through the Boost headers, tried to identify any re-definitions from my own code, etc. The Boost code causing the issue is as follows:

```
explicit packaged_task(R(*f)())  
{
    typedef R(*FR)();
    typedef detail::task_shared_state<FR,R> task_shared_state_type;
    task= task_ptr(new task_shared_state_type(f));
    future_obtained=false;
}
```

Thoughts on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you include a few relevant lines of code for those who don't have the libraries to hand? Maybe we could spot something.

Comment: You mean you just include `boost/thread.hpp`, but don't use anything from it? Then, probably you define a macro that messes-up boost headers. Probably something like `#define T 0`

Comment: Thank you. After significant digging, it appears that the actual issue is the definition of FR using _#define_ in the lpsolve library (vs. _typedef_ in Boost) which has an impact on the code in the Boost library. I am working on finding a solution. Once I do, I will post. Any other thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: @NeilKirk I used absolutely no Boost code. I just included the header file.